Override ngComponentTemplate from root component
I am trying to wrap my head around the following issue. In the root-level app.component you have the following structure:
<div class="container">
  <sidebar  />

  <menu-bar />

  <div class="h-full w-full overflow-auto">
    <main class="overflow-auto">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

The menu-bar is only used in some of the routes and even might change. Therefore I don't want to provide a specific implementation, but more or less:
<div class="container">
  <sidebar  />

  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="..." />

  <div class="h-full w-full overflow-auto">
    <main class="overflow-auto">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

This outlet should be provided by a child component (indirectly). The child component depends on the current route.
ASP.NET Blazor for example has a concept called SectionOutlet which describes exactly what I want:
Here the app.component.html:
<div class="container">
  <sidebar  />

  <section-outlet SectionName="menu-bar" />

  <div class="h-full w-full overflow-auto">
    <main class="overflow-auto">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

Now when I have a process page, this page can then easily provide the content:
process-page.component.html:
<section-content SectionName="menu-bar">
 <my-real-menu/>
</section>

<OtherContent/>

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Angular?

Here are two ways to do this.
You can write a switchStatement or if statement that returns the correct menu component based on the route used.
private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
menuComp: any;
getMenu() {
     if(this.router.url.includes('/a-route') {
          this.menuComp = AMenuComponent
     } else if(this.router.url.includes('/b-route') {
          this.menuComp = BMenuComponent
     }
}

Then on router events navigation you trigger the logic to rerun.
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub.add(
    this.router.events.subscribe(value => {
        if(value instanceof NavigationEnd)    
          this.getMenu();
        })
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

Finally use this property to dynamically create the menu.
<div class="container">
  <sidebar  />

  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="menuComp" />

  <div class="h-full w-full overflow-auto">
    <main class="overflow-auto">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>


Another way is to use this same approach is to specify the component on the route data property.
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'a-route', component: AComponent, data: { menu: AMenuComponent } },
];

The on the component root, subscribe to the data changes on the first child, then you can access this component and render using component outlet.
private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
menuComp: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub.add(
    this.activatedRoute.firstChild.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.menuComp = data.menu;
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

Same html for this as above method.

Interesting approach. Thanks.
This this.activatedRoute.firstChild.data will always give me an empty object. Is this due to the fact that app.component is outside of router-outlet?

Figured - it was loadChildren which was the problem
